# Could not process SSAS cube using C# code

Tags: azure, ssas, cube, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I have a c# code that I am using to refresh the cube on azure analysis service. I am using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64 library to process the cube. The code runs fine and process facts and measures on azure anlysis service without any issue from my LOCAL MACHINE.
Then I uploaded my code to a server machine to run the processing.

When I start the processing job, I get the following error:

```
[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate type missing from ADAL resource.
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.LoadAndValidateType(Assembly assembly, String typeName)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.LoadServicePrincipalTypes(Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary..ctor()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.get_Instance()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AadAuthenticator.AcquireToken(String resource, String dataSource, String identityProvider, String tenantId, String userId, String password, Boolean useAdalCache, Boolean useAdTranslation)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenHttpConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString)
exception: [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate type missing from ADAL resource.
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.LoadAndValidateType(Assembly assembly, String typeName)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.LoadServicePrincipalTypes(Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary..ctor()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdalRuntimeLibrary.get_Instance()
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AadAuthenticator.AcquireToken(String resource, String dataSource, String identityProvider, String tenantId, String userId, String password, Boolean useAdalCache, Boolean useAdTranslation)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenHttpConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString)
```

Anyone has any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Seems like it's trying to load ADAL.NET at runtime.. Maybe the right DLL is not deployed?

Comment: But the error is saying it is missing some certificates. And it runs and build fine locally without the dll.

Comment: No it is complaining it can't load a type. It's trying to load a class from ADAL.

Comment: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate class is available inside Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll which is added and is available in the project..

Comment: :/ That's pretty weird then...